# Better way to test SQL logic gates

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

I wanted to test some logic gates that I wrote for a query. Glad I did because I wrote the code late in the day and it turned out to have a relatively obvious error.

I want to know if there is any way to make the code cleaner or just look better. I'm thinking the 2 areas that could use improvement are -

- How I select the results. Right now this is a case statement that returns 1 or 0, but is there a way to just write something like `select (x and y)`
- How I generate the true/false permutations. I've considered populating a single temp table with 1/0 and reusing it with aliases, but that doesn't clean up TOO much.

```
select x, y, z, case when (x=1 and y=1 or z=1) then 1 else 0 end as ResultOne, case when (x=1 and (y=1 or z=1)) then 1 else 0 end as ResultTwo
from 
(   select 1 x
    union
    select 0 x
) as A
inner join
(   select 1 y
    union
    select 0 y
) as B on 1=1
inner join
(   select 1 z
    union
    select 0 z
) as C on 1=1
order by x,y,z
```

[image: Query result set]

Answer (score 0):

You can use table valued constructors for something like this pretty easily. Much simpler than all those joins to subqueries. Although with such a small amount of data I don't think it makes much difference. And use a cross join instead of 1 = 1. That is what they are for.

```
select a.x
    , b.y
    , c.z
    , case when (a.x = 1 and b.y = 1 or c.z = 1) then 1 else 0 end as ResultOne
    , case when (a.x = 1 and (b.y = 1 or c.z = 1)) then 1 else 0 end as ResultTwo
from (values(0),(1)) a(x)
cross join (values(0),(1)) b(y)
cross join (values(0),(1)) c(z)
```

Comment: I like this a lot. The joins make much more sense. I've also never heard of a cross join so this was very informative. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without table valued constructors, with some math.

```
select a.x
      ,b.y
      ,c.z
      ,case when (a.x + b.y = 2 or c.z = 1) then 1 else 0 end ResultOne
      ,case when (a.x = 1 and b.y + c.z >= 1) then 1 else 0 end ResultTwo
from (select 1 x union select 0) a
cross join (select 1 y union select 0) b
cross join (select 1 z union select 0) c;
```